# Error when using mathtext.fontset = 'custom' in stylelib

Tags: matplotlib

I encounter a strange behavior using matplotlib when I try define a custom math font (with usetex=false):

mpl.__version__ = '2.0.2' with python 2.7

I define a stylesheet (i.e. `*.mplstyle` file in stylelib folder) in which I write

```
mathtext.fontset = 'custom'
mathtext.rm = 'Avenir Next'
mathtext.it = 'Avenir Next:italic'
mathtext.bf = 'Avenir Next:bold'
mathtext.fallback_to_cm : True
```

If I try to make a plot with that style I get the error:

```
Bad key "mathtext.rm = 'Avenir Next" on line 49 in
/Users/gp/.matplotlib/stylelib/simple.mplstyle.
You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template
or from the matplotlib source distribution
 UserWarning: In /Users/gp/.matplotlib/stylelib/simple.mplstyle: Illegal line #48
"mathtext.fontset = 'custom'
"
in file "/Users/gp/.matplotlib/stylelib/simple.mplstyle"
```

And also similar errors about `mathtext.it` and `mathtext.bf`.

If I instead comment these lines out and just write into the py document that I use to generate the plot (after loading the style with the now commented lines about mathtext) the following lines than everything works flawless (w/o error and with the expected behavior).

```
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = 'Avenir Next'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.it'] = 'Avenir Next:italic'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'Avenir Next:bold'
```

I am puzzled because the lines of my stylesheet are as described in the matplotlib documentary. Can somebody make anything of it?

Georg

edit: typos

Answer (score 2):

After sitting over it for some days I posted the question just to realize directly afterwards that the syntax in the style file is wrong at several places.
The single quotation marks don't belong there. Also the `=`must be replaced by colons `:`.

Then it works!